# Axios GET call works in browser but not in Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to make a GET call using Axios (on Safari):

```
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "https://politicsandwar.com/api/tradeprice/?resource=steel&key=KEY",
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
          responseType: "json",
          crossorigin: true
        }
      }).then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

I changed the headers hoping to fix any CORS issues. But I still get a Network Error:

```
{
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js:2:9728\nhttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js:2:8492",
  "config": {
    "url": "https://politicsandwar.com/api/tradeprice/?resource=steel&key=73d021ddbee7ab",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
      "responseType": "json",
      "crossorigin": true
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1
  }
}
```

I tried putting the link directly into my browser. It works, so I know it's not a problem with my connection.

What else can I try?

Edit: I was testing this in Codepen if that matters.

Comment: I would guess that CodePen is blocking the request. Try the same code locally.

Comment: You can't set Access Control headers in the request. They must be set server side. If API isn't CORS enabled you need to use a proxy, either on server you control or a third party service

Comment: CodePen was indeed blocking the request.

Answer (score 1):

CodePen was blocking the request. Thanks @clyde-frog!